# Direct2D ID2D1RenderTarget::EndDraw and zoom

Tags: c++, directx, zooming, direct2d

I am developing a native `Direct2D` application in C++. All my drawing calls are properly used between the `BeginDraw` and [EndDraw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371924(v=vs.85).aspx) `ID2D1RenderTarget` methods.

Unfortunately I noticed a strange behavior of the `EndDraw` method whenever the zoom increases up to a certain, but not defined, point. Indeed, if I keep increasing the zoom by using the `ID2D1RenderTarget::SetTransform` method, it reaches a point where my application stops working and remains blocked for few minutes. I would like to highlight that after the method returns the graphic elements are properly rendered into the screen.

I was able to debug the application and check that it stops when the `EndDraw` method is called, but I couldn't get more information.

Is there any known workaround of fix for this behavior?

Comment: Is your zoom variable an `int` or a `float`? Is it overflowing? Underflowing?

Comment: @IvanRubinson It is a float, and the last time I checked it was equal to about 192 after the EndDraw method returned.

Comment: Also, according to the shapes and the center of the zoom, it never stops with the previous and with the next values of zoom.